# Returns wrong result For printing FIRST AND LAST DATE OF THE MONTH in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, output, nsdate

I need the first and last date of the month using current date. I have found lots of solutions for this. But all gives me wrong answer.

My code:
1. First Date of the month

```
extension NSDate{

    func firstDateOfMonth ()->NSDate{

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: self)
        let startOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
        return startOfMonth

    } 

    func lastDateOfmonth()->NSDate{

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let comps2 = NSDateComponents()
        comps2.month = 1
        comps2.day = -1
        let endOfMonth = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(comps2, toDate: self, options: [])!
        return endOfMonth
    }

}
```

Result looks like this:

```
print(NSDate().firstDateOfMonth())
print(NSDate().lastDateOfmonth())
```

Output:

```
2016-01-31 18:30:00 +0000  // instead of 2016-02-01
// prints the previous month last date
2016-03-02 06:56:17 +0000   // instead of 2016-02-29
// next month date
```

Please correct if anything is wrong

And I tried this code also

```
extension NSDate{

    func firstDateOfMonths ()->NSDate{

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

        let components = calendar.components([.Era, .Year,.Month], fromDate: self)
        components.day = 1
        let startOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
        return startOfMonth

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way to calculate days is `rangeOfUnit` of `NSCalendar`

```
extension NSDate {

  func firstDateOfMonth() -> NSDate {

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    // calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) use this line if you need UTC
    var startDate : NSDate?
    calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Month, startDate: &startDate, interval: nil, forDate: self)
    return startDate!
  }

  func lastDateOfMonth() -> NSDate {

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    // calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) use this line if you need UTC
    let dayRange = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Day, inUnit: .Month, forDate: self)
    let dayLength = dayRange.length
    let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: self)
    components.day = dayLength

    return calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
  }
}
```

**Swift 3+**

In `Calendar` the API is named `dateInterval(of:start:interval:for:`

```
extension Date {

    func firstDateOfMonth() -> Date {

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var startDate = Date()
        var interval : TimeInterval = 0
        _ = calendar.dateInterval(of:.month, start: &startDate, interval: &interval, for: self)
        return startDate
    }

    func lastDateOfMonth() -> Date {

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let dayRange = calendar.range(of:.day, in: .month, for: self)!
        let dayLength = dayRange.upperBound
        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)
        components.day = dayLength

        return calendar.date(from:components)!
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any need to convert UTC to local time?

Comment: if i change region in ipad , Using this line     // calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) use this line if you need UTC
sometimes produce wrong date.My app is used in world wide means , the above code is reliable or not.Please let me know.I just want update date with current user settings and region.

Comment: Exactly my question, I know the NsDate() gives UTC , so when need exact(user's locale) date what is need to do.

Comment: Although the output of `print()` of an `NSDate` value in the debug console displays always UTC, `NSCalendar` and `NSDateFormatter` consider the current system locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is the common problem that you don't understand how NSDate works. NSDate returns UTC, not a date in your time zone. There are hundreds of questions explaining this.

The second problem is you being careless by getting all date components. You are adding one month minus one day to the current date.